# Failed to handle RealmList<RealmList<RealmInt>> in Realm.io

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-list

My JSON data looks like this from server api

```
{
  //...
  PredecessorIds:[[1,2][3,4][5]]
  //...
}
```

I can successfully handle the arrays of Integer or String by `RealmList<RealmInt>` but this time I failed with an error, because RealmList> is not supported saying, `"Type parameter 'io.realm.realmList' is not within its bounds...."`

For `RealmInt` see [this link](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/1a97377df0c49cd4fca9).

I tried to solve it using `RealmList<RealmLista>` where RealmLista extends from `RealmObject` and has a `RealmList` like this

```
public class RealmLista extends RealmObject {
public RealmList<RealmInt> value;
public RealmLista() {
}

public RealmLista(RealmList<RealmInt> val) {
  this.value = val;
}
```

}

and then created a `RealmListaTypeAdapter` and added it to Gson but when deserializing `Gson expects an Object (RealmLista) but is found array`, as the data shown above from server is obvious.

```
//RealmListAdapter for Gson
@Override
public RealmLista read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    RealmLista lista = new RealmLista();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //how to read that [[1],[3,4]] int into RealmLista
    in.beginArray();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        lista.value.add(new RealmInt(in.nextInt()));
    }
    in.endArray();
    return lista;
}
```

Is there any way to store a simple `List<List<Integer>>` by converting to `RealmObject` of any type while saving, `List<List<Integer>>` is easily converted by Gson. :-/

Comment: [This works for mere `RealmList<RealmInteger>](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/1a97377df0c49cd4fca9) but you do need a new object that stores a `RealmList` of realm ints if you want to store an array of them.

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't support lists of lists currently. See  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2549.

So @EpicPandaForce's idea about creating a RealmObject that holds that inner list is probably the best work-around.

It could look something like this:

```
public class Top extends RealmObject {
  private RealmList<ChildList> list;
}

public class ChildList extends RealmObject {
  private RealmList<RealmInt> list;
}

public class RealmInt extends RealmObject {
  private int i;
}
```

The correct link for the gist should be: https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/1a97377df0c49cd4fca9

Comment: I am already doing it. The problem is with Gson. It is not accepting an object(having array) where I am receiving a direct array.

Comment: It sounds like you should create a a custom GSON deserializer. There is an example in the gist.

Comment: Can you see my Adapter in the question, I am facing problem in reading Object while Array is found or I need to add another question?